# Setter method in Property Method

Tags: python, getter-setter

```
class Book:
def __init__(self):
    self.title=input("Enter a book name:")
    self.author=input("Enter book author:")
    self.publisher=input("Enter book publication:")
    self.price=int(input("Enter book price:"))
def get_book(self):
    print(self.title)
    print(self.author)
    print(self.publisher)
    print(self.price)
def set_title(self, title):
    self.title=title
def set_author(self, authr):
    self.author=authr
def set_publisher(self, publish):
    self.publisher=publish
def set_price(self, price):
    self.price=price


    
Book=property(get_book, set_book)'''
```

I am trying to put all these setter methods inside one property method?
or is there a way to combine all these setter methods so that Property method can access all the instance variables one by one?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make property in your class you have to add `@property` decorator before function, and `@name_of_property.setter` before setter function.

For example:

```
class Book:
    def __init__(self):
        self.title=input("Enter a book name:")
        self.author=input("Enter book author:")
        self.publisher=input("Enter book publication:")
        self.price=int(input("Enter book price:"))
    @property
    def book(self):
        print(self.title)
        print(self.author)
        print(self.publisher)
        print(self.price)
    @book.setter
    def book(self,value):
        #your code, for example:
        print(value)
    def set_title(self, title):
        self.title=title
    def set_author(self, authr):
        self.author=authr
    def set_publisher(self, publish):
        self.publisher=publish
    def set_price(self, price):
        self.price=price


book = Book()
book.book#will print out title,author,publisher
book.book=30#will print 30
```

Comment: is there a way to use just one instance variable for all the setter methods?